# Sum of a multidimensional Array php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

i have the following array:

```
Array (  [0] => Array(  [data] => 2018-06-08
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1
                        [segundos] => 10089 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 2 
                        [segundos] => 6300 ) 
        [2] => Array  ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) 
        [3] => Array (  [data] => 2018-06-09
                        [grupo] => 1
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) )
```

How can i sum the key[segundos], where the keys [data] and [maq] are the same?

the output:

```
Array (  [0] => Array( [data] => 2018-06-08
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1
                        [segundos] => 13689 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 2 
                        [segundos] => 6300 ) 
        [2] => Array (  [data] => 2018-06-09
                        [grupo] => 1
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) :

```
$second_array = array_reduce($first_array, function($carry, $item) {
    $key = sprintf('%s-%s', $item['data'], $item['maq']);
    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key]['segundos'] += $item['segundos'];
    } else {
        $carry[$key] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Then to get rid of the keys used above you can do:

```
$second_array = array_values($second_array);
```